# {Pafy Problem} How can i change video name in pafy

Tags: python, pafy

### I want to know how to change the name of the downloaded video or add to it

```
import pafy
url = str(input("Youtube video URL :"))
video = pafy.new(url)
stream = video.streams
stream[0].download()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `stream[0].download()`, add a string argument with your desired filename and extension, for example `stream[0].download("example.mp4")`.

See [the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Pafy/#stream-methods) for more info.